# AsyncHttpClient LoopJ and preserving data from onSuccess method

Tags: android, json, asynchronous, loopj, asynchttpclient

I have this method called "invokeWS". All I want to is to do is to update an   ArrayAdapter adapter2 I use in my app with the listdata ArrayList that gets data from a JSON file. I tried different things.

- The onSuccess is void, so I cannot return anything to the main program. I am good to go inside the try, JSON is parsed and I can see the strings I want in the console but as soon as I get out of the onSuccess, I get an empty Arraylist. So when returning the listdata is empty.
- Had to also declare the listdata "final", otherwise errors of "accessed from inner class" would appear wherever listdata is on OnSuccess
- Also Tried to make the ArrayAdapter adapter2 to be updated inside onSuccess but didn't work because it is said it is out of scope.
- I was going to implement onFinish method, but it even got called before JSON was parsed for a strange reason.

  ```
  public static ArrayList<String> invokeWS() {
  AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
  final  ArrayList<String>  listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
  client.get("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8085/CompanyJersWS/company/showcompany", new  JsonHttpResponseHandler() {  //address to be specified each time, using external IP address


              @Override
              public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                  System.out.println("Inside Success invokeWS");
                  try {
                      JSONArray json = response.getJSONArray("Companies");
                      System.out.println("JSON is parsed!" +json.toString() + "Length is " + json.length());
                      System.out.println("First value is " + json.getString(0));
                      int i;
                      for (i=0;i<json.length();i++)
                          listdata.add(json.getString(i));
                      System.out.println("Listdata contains" +listdata);


                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println("FAILED invokeWS");
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }



  );

  System.out.println("Listdata out of scope contains" +listdata);

  return listdata;

  }
  ```

  This is how I am trying to call invokeWS() from my main class;

  ```
  ArrayList<String> tempval = invokeWS();
  ```

  and this is the adapter2 written in main class, which i want to have listdata   from json file as contents.

  ```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tempval.toArray(new String[tempval.size()]));
   sp1.setAdapter(adapter2);
  ```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you can do is, after onSuccess pass the "listdata" that you create like a parameter of a function (for example **"refreshData"**):

```
    @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println("Inside Success invokeWS");
            try {
                JSONArray json = response.getJSONArray("Companies");
                System.out.println("JSON is parsed!" +json.toString() + "Length is " + json.length());
                System.out.println("First value is " + json.getString(0));
                int i;
                for (i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                    listdata.add(json.getString(i));
                 }
             System.out.println("Listdata contains" +listdata);
             refreshData(listdata);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("FAILED invokeWS");
                e.printStackTrace();
             }

        }
```

And then use that function to update the array with the new list:

```
public void refreshData(ArrayList<String> listdata){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listdata);
   sp1.setAdapter(adapter2);

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm having to problems to the solution you suggested though!

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it!
Thanks for suggesting this! I also had to initialize sp1 once again, because otherwise it was out of scope, but good idea!


              Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);